# How do I add permissions via command line for "everyone" on external HDD

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I have an external HDD and I kind of messed up the file permissions but when fixing it I thought it is ok bc with my username I can access the files perfectly fine. Now that I use this with two PC (actually ATM I don't have access to my other PC) I can't access these files.

The problem is this directory has hundreds of folders with no permission for "everyone". I would like to give it the default permissions including have all access for the user "everyone". How do I do that via command line for these hundreds of folders?

Comment: Try `TAKEOWN /A` to give ownership to the Administrator group, and then `ICACLS` to modify the permissions.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use  `takeown` to take ownership of the file

```
takeown /r /d y /f *
```

^ Recursively takes ownership of all files without prompting "are you sure".

Follow it up with `icacls` set the access control list

```
icacls * /t  /grant Everyone:F
```

This will recursively grant Full access to user group "Everyone" to all files in the folder.

Comment: Ownership takeover can also happen via `icacls`: `Icacls * /setowner %USERNAME% /T /C /L`. However not combined in a single command with step two (sadly).

Comment: Thanks for this. I used a semicolon and specified a certain directory like this: `takeown /f "e:\Users\myUserName" /r /d y; icacls "e:\Users\myUserName" /t /grant myUserName:f`

Comment: +1. Saved my day when copying back a ton of user's MP3 files originally taken from his home directory. Native Windows "Security" GUI was ultimately stupid -- it assigned "Everyone" to folders, but all files remained intact and thus inaccessible... We all love Windows "security" for that. :)

Comment: Well, I managed to run the icalc command by mistake with my username replaced, in my Windows folder. Fingers crossed. @FrankN :)

Answer (score 0):

This set owner of folder or file to group "Everyone" command works on windows 7 and above:

```
icacls "full path of file with file extension" /setowner "Everyone" /T /C
```